# Oracle SQL unpivot and keep rows with null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently doing an `unpivot` for a `Oracle Data Source (v.12.2)` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
    UNPIVOT (
    (X,Y,Val) 
    FOR SITE 
    IN ( 
        (SITE1_X, SITE1_Y, SITE1_VAL) AS '1',
        (SITE2_X, SITE2_Y, SITE2_VAL) AS '2',
        (SITE3_X, SITE3_Y, SITE3_VAL) AS '3'
    ))
```

This works totally fine so far. There is only one exception - I have another column, let's say `extend_info`, ... if this column has the value `y`, there will be only one row of this column and all the site columns will be `null`. Nevertheless I would like to keep this row and not drop it.

I'm not really sure how to do this or what would be a nice way to do this. Any recommendations?

**Example:**

*Original Table:*

```
ID | SITE1_X | SITE1_Y |SITE1_VAL | SITE2_X | SITE2_Y | SITE2_VAL | ... | extend_info
-------
1  | 0       | 0       | 5        | 1       | 1       | 10        | ... | n
2  | 0       | 0       | 3        | null    | null    | null      | ... | n
3  | null    | null    | null     | null    | null    | null      | ... | y
```

*current output:*

```
ID | SITE | X | Y | VAL | extend_info
-------
1  | 1    | 0 | 0 | 5   | n       
2  | 1    | 1 | 1 | 10  | n   
3  | 2    | 0 | 0 | 3   | n
```

*desired output:*

```
ID | SITE | X | Y | VAL | extend_info
-------
1  | 1    | 0 | 0 | 5   | n       
2  | 1    | 1 | 1 | 10  | n   
3  | 2    | 0 | 0 | 3   | n
4  |      |   |   |     | y
```

I don't really care what is in `SITE|X|Y|VAL` in that case, can be `0` for everything or `null`.

***Bonus question:***
If `extend_info` is `y` I would like to join another table with this ID. The other table looks like this:

```
ID | F_ID | X | Y | VAL
-----
1  | 4    | 1 | 1 | 8
2  | 4    | 2 | 2 | 9
```

and in that case my final output table should look like:

```
ID | SITE | X | Y | VAL | X_OTHER_TABLE | Y_OTHER_TABLE
-------
1  | 1    | 0 | 0 | 5   |        
2  | 1    | 1 | 1 | 10  |    
3  | 2    | 0 | 0 | 3   | 
4  |      |   |   | 8   | 1             | 1
5  |      |   |   | 9   | 2             | 2
```

I know... the database structure is super ugly but that is what a vendor provides us and we are trying to create a `View` to make it easier to perform some data analysis tasks on it.

It doesn't have to look 1:1 like my final example - but maybe my itention gets clear = I want to have one single table/view with all the information in a single format.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a lateral join:

```
SELECT s.id, u.*
FROM some_table s CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT s.SITE1_X as SITE_X, s.SITE1_Y as SITE_Y, s.SITE1_VAL as SITE_VAL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT s.SITE2_X, s.SITE2_Y, s.SITE2_VAL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT s.SITE3_X, s.SITE3_Y, s.SITE3_VAL FROM DUAL
     ) u;
```

You can just join additional tables to this as you like.

Comment: Can you please explain `u(SITE_X, SITE_Y, SITE_VAL)`? Is that adding aliases to the results of u? When I try to test something similar, I get errors.

Comment: @PatrickH . . . Ooops, I fixed that.  It was some wishful coding that Oracle supported `VALUES()`.